# `git difftool` and witespaces in namefiles

Tags: git, path, whitespace

It seems that when `git difftool` executes an external command, it does not quote the arguments correctly.

If `.gitconfig` contains the following lines:

```
[difftool.echo]
  cmd = echo "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

When I try to run `difftool` with a path containing spaces, such as

```
> git difftool -t echo HEAD^ HEAD spaces\ here/test.txt
```

I get the following result:

```
/tmp/RL2Nyi_test.txt spaces here/test.txt
```

As you can see, the filenames are not quoted (despite the explicit quotes in the command), hence the argument parsing fails. Removing the quotes in `.gitconfig` (EDIT: as well as escaping them as `\"`) does not change the result.

(by replacing `echo` with any diff program, you get a more meaningful use case).

How can I get properly escaped filenames?

Comment: I think you have to escape the quotes: `cmd = echo \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"`

Comment: I tried that as well, still no change.

Comment: What about `cmd = "echo \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""`, and `cmd = "echo '$LOCAL' '$REMOTE'"`?

Comment: Still no change with the first one (quote-ception); the second at least gives a change: it outputs the literal string `$LOCAL $REMOTE`. Not what we wanted though...

Comment: Correction: For some reason that is not entirely clear to me, when I use your first version `cmd = echo \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"` with `echo` as the command, as I was doing in my previous tests, it gives the unescaped filenames, but then replacing `echo` with the command name of a diff tool (`latexdiff` in my case) works, in the sense that it runs on the correct files instead of choking on the spaces. I suspect that some magic is going on here with arguments containing whitespaces. So I have got a working solution for my real-life problem. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesB, since your comment led to a solution, perhaps you should post it as an answer for Federico to accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to escape quotes around the command in `.gitconfig`:

```
cmd = difftoolname \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Comment: Thanks again! As noted in the comments, this works for my use case, although the version with `echo` still does not print quotes around the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[difftool.echo]
    cmd = 'echo "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
```

Wrapping the entire command in single quotes causes Git to treat it as a single string, which gets assigned to the `diftool.echo` command unmodified. This is what we want.

This is very similar to one [suggested in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087026/git-difftool-and-witespaces-in-namefiles#comment31718390_21087026), which didn't work:

```
# This won't work
cmd = "echo '$LOCAL' '$REMOTE'"
```

The reason that this doesn't work has to do with the way quotes are handled in Bash (and most shells in general). This assigns `echo '$LOCAL' '$REMOTE'` as the command, but single quotes will *not* expand variables. This is why you were getting a literal output of `$LOCAL $REMOTE`.

The inner double-quotes in the working version at the top of this post will allow the arguments inside them to be expanded.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Fails with `/usr/lib/git-core/git-difftool--helper: 1: eval: echo $LOCAL $REMOTE: not found`. I guess in this way it looks for an executable file called 'echo $LOCAL $REMOTE'